# How can I validate the value from bool in the view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, boolean

In my Controller I have a bool value isInList.

```
List<int> listManager = new List<int>() { 123,3231 };

bool isInList = listManager.Contains(newint);
```

In my view i want to show some data only if the value of bool is true.
How can I accomplish this?

```
@if(@Model.isInList == true)
     {
        ..show this view data...
     }
```

In Model:

```
 public class IndexHome
    {

        bool isInList { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: How are you sending this value to the view?  Ideally it would be a property on the view model.  What's your view model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you want to pass the data from the Controller into the View

You do this by doing 2 things

1. In the Controller `return View("SomeViewName", viewModel);`
2. In the View itself, at the top you must declare what the model type is.. e.g. `@model myNamsespace.Web.ViewModels.SearchViewModel`

After you do this you should have access to `@Model.SomeProperty` inside your view